# use squeryl with Play 2

Tags: scala, playframework, squeryl

I am new with Play and Scala and I am trying to import squeryl at build.sbt but without success. I am following the Play for Scala book.

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.squeryl#squeryl;0.9.5-6: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.squeryl:squeryl:0.9.5-6 (/home/felipe/workspace-play/products/build.sbt#L9-20)
[warn]        +- products:products_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.squeryl#squeryl;0.9.5-6: not found
```

Here is my build.sbt

```
name := """products"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  evolutions,
  "org.squeryl" % "squeryl" % "0.9.5-6",
  // "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.4.0",
  "net.sf.barcode4j" % "barcode4j" % "2.0",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
resolvers += "Sonatype releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
resolvers += "webjars" at "http://webjars.github.com/m2"
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed for "org.squeryl" % "squeryl_2.9.0-1" % "0.9.4" and it worked.